# Odd result using multiple - operator in C#

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I got an odd bug today. Look at this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 5;
            int y = 10;
            int z = y - -x;
            Console.WriteLine(z);
        }
    }
}
```

The code compile fine (no error and no warning) and display 15! I think the behaviour is a bit odd. I don't know if it is supposed to be like this or not. However you can write really silly code like this:

```
int z = y - - - + + + + - - - - - - - - x;
```

N.B. the space between the operators is important.
z is 5 because the plus symbols haven't any effect and the number of minus symbols is odd.

Is there any reason to support this operator behaviour? Is it intentional or a kind of bug? There is any flag to set in order to get at least a warning?

Cheers

Comment: Is there any reason not to support it? Do you think the compiler team should spend time adding these kinds of "smarts" to the compiler so that you cannot "accidentally" write silly code like this? The main reason to support it is the usual: that's a valid C# expression, according to the specification. Another strong reason is the fact that it uses correct arithmetic. Should that be a bug?

Comment: this is basic aritmetic. where do you think is the bug ?

Comment: Technically it is a valid operation, if you work your way through the operations it ends up as `int z = y - x` which would equal 5, which is also what that operation returns. It may look silly but works as it should.

Comment: It even makes sense in expressions like `int x = y * -1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with it at all. It's subtracting -5 from 10 - i.e. it's using the unary - operator to turn 5 to -5, and then the binary operator to perform the subtraction. I can't think of any similar languages (C, Java etc) where this *wouldn't* be valid.

I don't think it's a bug, and I very much doubt that there are any options to make this a warning.

I need to be slightly careful about the terminology here, but I believe the binding of the operators is controlled by their *precedence* as per section 7.3.1 of the C# spec. You can think of a unary operator as "binding tighter" than a binary operator.

Comment: Admittedly it's a little less useful in C#.  In C and C++ that sort of expression can easily result from macro expansion.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a bug. `10 - -5` is *indeed* `15`. Subtracting `-5` is identical to adding `5`.

And you can negate a number any even number of times you want, and you'll end up with that number. Any odd number of negations will give you the negation. In other words:

```
5 == -(-(-(-5)))
```

Comment: you miss my point, the expression is legal but it is not practically useful or at least misleading. I think the compiler should flag such expression like others "legal" expression.

Comment: If it's truly `10 - -5`, the compiler will almost certainly constant-fold that to just `15` anyway, it's not like the runtime is doing any more work. As to whether it's misleading, no, I disagree. Your _second_ example with the plethora of signs _is_ confusing but, if someone wants to write crappy legal code, it's not up to the compiler to stop them. Otherwise it wouldn't _be_ legal.

Answer (score 1):

That statement makes complete sense.

You have a double negative. -- is equivalent to + so you're really writing:

```
int z = y + x; // Obviously 15
```

...basic math concept.

Answer (score 1):

You're just using multiple instances of unary plus/minus.  Odd, but not necessarily wrong.  I suspect that the cost to detect and prevent this type of usage is too high relative to the odds that someone will actually do it in real code.  Plus, it's only hard to read, not technically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much how I was taught to do maths. If you remove -5 from 10, what else would you expect to get apart from 15.

If you have a philosphical point about maths, then you probably need to ask it over at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I doubt the people on math.SE want philosophical questions there.

Comment: Reading the FAQ, I think they might well be interested in it.

Comment: In fact I asked them, lets see what they think. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26004

Comment: And, in transferring it to math.se, you've _totally_ stuffed it up. It's _not_ adding neg to neg, `10 - -5` is _not_ `5` and you shouldn't be the _least_ bit happy about the transcription errors - I'm just glad you're not my DNA :-)

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't a *philosophical* question. It is just a (very simple) math question.

Comment: At it's core all maths is philosophical, for instance 0, how exactly can you have nothing?! You can't, unless your philosophical view point tells you that it's ok. We've wrapped up a bunch of ideas and over time called them maths, which is fine by me, but it is a philosophical  choice.

Comment: There is a branch of philosophy that is appropriately called the [philosophy of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics) that deals with philosophical issues surrounding mathematics. The laws of arithmetic are not a part of that.

Comment: actually the question was very concrete. Should the compiler warning for something that it is legal but it is also probably a typo? Why a legal but not-useful functionality (at least for built-in type) is supported? The same code with () around the operator is clearly intentional. I am sorry if I wasn't completly clear asking the question.